# How to add table headers on every FPDF page

Tags: php, fpdf

Note the picture below. i want put table header on page 2 like table header on page 1.
[image]

I used the below code and when use the header function it gave me the below error.

> $pdf' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\karyawan\upah\cetak_upah_h.php on line 75

This is my code :

```
    require_once ("../fpdf/fpdf.php");
        class h4PDF extends FPDF{
        function Header(){
            $this->Cell(0.5, 1, "No", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(3, 1, "Nama", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(2.9, 0.5, "Masuk Kerja", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(1.5, 0.5, "Lembur", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(0.5, 0.5, "Pre", "T", '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(5, 0.5, "Upah", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(3.75, 0.5, "Lembur", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(1.25, 1, "Premi", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(1.5, 1, "Total", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Ln(0.5);
            $this->Cell(3.5, 0.5, "", 0, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(0.6, 0.5, "Hari", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(1, 0.5, "1/2Hari", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(0.5, 0.5, "UT", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(0.8, 0.5, "Jam", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(0.5, 0.5, "1", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(0.5, 0.5, "2", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(0.5, 0.5, "Lbr", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(0.5, 0.5, "mi", 1, 'B', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(1.25, 0.5, "Kerja", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(1.25, 0.5, "1/2 Hari", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(1.25, 0.5, "UT", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(1.25, 0.5, "Sejam", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(1.25, 0.5, "Lb 1", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(1.25, 0.5, "Lb 2", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Cell(1.25, 0.5, "Lb Libur", 1, '0', "C", false);
            $this->Ln(0.5);
        }
    }

$pdf = new FPDF('P','cm',array(21.5,33));

$pdf->AddFont('verdana','','verdana.php');

$pdf->AddFont('verdanaB','','verdanaB.php');

$pdf->setTopMargin(1);

$pdf->setLeftMargin(0.6);

$pdf->setRightMargin(0.6);

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);

$pdf->SetFont('verdanaB','','12');

$pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);

$pdf->SetDrawColor( 0, 0, 0, 255);

$pdf = new h4PDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
```

**Note: page can be more than two**

Comment: You problem is here `$pdf = new FPDF('P','cm',array(21.5,33));` and the error you're getting is because of that the variables are not passing also you don't need to call the same function twice header will be created at the top of the page calling it once before `AddPage()` will create the headers for you. [This](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto2.htm) will help you to understand how to use the header

Comment: In your initial questions you didn't show us the entire code where you used these `('P','cm',array(21.5,33))`. In fpdf header function will allow you to create the header of the document and then call it it's an extension to the FPDF header.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have solved the problem. problem solved when im aply this $pdf = new h4PDF('P','cm',array(21.5,33));

Comment: Grate and always happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a header function and extend the FPDF. Below is an example code you can experiment with it.

Header:

```
class h4PDF extends FPDF{
    function Header(){
        $this->Image('../../images/logo.png', 10,6,30);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
        $this->Cell(80);
        $this->Cell(50, 10, 'Report Name', 0, 0,'C');
        $this->Ln(10);    
        $this->SetFont('verdana','','8');
        $this->Cell(0.5, 1, "No", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(3, 1, "Nama", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(2.9, 0.5, "Masuk Kerja", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(1.5, 0.5, "Lembur", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(0.5, 0.5, "Pre", "T", '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(5, 0.5, "Upah", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(3.75, 0.5, "Lembur", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(1.25, 1, "Premi", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(1.5, 1, "Total", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Ln(0.5);
        $this->Cell(3.5, 0.5, "", 0, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(0.6, 0.5, "Hari", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(1, 0.5, "1/2Hari", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(0.5, 0.5, "UT", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(0.8, 0.5, "Jam", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(0.5, 0.5, "1", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(0.5, 0.5, "2", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(0.5, 0.5, "Lbr", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(0.5, 0.5, "mi", 1, 'B', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(1.25, 0.5, "Kerja", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(1.25, 0.5, "1/2 Hari", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(1.25, 0.5, "UT", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(1.25, 0.5, "Sejam", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(1.25, 0.5, "Lb 1", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(1.25, 0.5, "Lb 2", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Cell(1.25, 0.5, "Lb Libur", 1, '0', "C", false);
        $this->Ln(0.5);
    }
}
```

When you start the creation of your PDF call the above function,

```
$pdf = new h4PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

while(odbc_fetch_row($pjk)){
//Skip.. (This code is too long to display)
if($no==61){$pdf->AddPage();}

//Skip.. (This code is too long to display)

}
```

Comment: I edited the code because the first one had a heading from one of my projects you can add the logo and the report name if you don't want them you can just remove them too.

Comment: this not work. this give me an error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$pdf' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in D:\xampp\htdocs\karyawan\upah\cetak_upah_h.php on line 75

Comment: So does the code work when you remove the function ?

Comment: no. This works if I delete the function. so hhere I put the function?

Comment: Well if you can update the question and post the code as it is with the above function I gave you so we can have look and help you.

Comment: OK.I will do it soon

Comment: after that just let me know in the comments

Comment: I have edited the code. at this code i did not find any error. but its display a blank page

Comment: i have new question in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856504/echoing-variable-in-header-function-fpdf . can you help me?