# echoing variable in header function FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

i will echoing variable in header function.
i have variable code like this :

```
$bulan=array("","Jan","Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mei", "Jun", "jul", "Agust", "Sept", "Okt", "Nop", "Des");
$tgl1=$_GET['tgl1']; //2017-08-10
$tgl2=$_GET['tgl2']; //2017-08-15
$tg1=substr($tgl1,8); //10
$tg2=substr($tgl2,8); //15
$bln1=$bulan[substr($tgl1,5,2)*1]; //Agust
$bln2=$bulan[substr($tgl2,5,2)*1]; //Agust
$thn=substr($tgl2,0,4); //2017
```

in my header function have code to echoing variable like this:

```
$this->Cell(20, 0.5, 'Tanggal '.$tg1.' '.$bln1.' - '.$tg2.' '.$bln2.' '.$thn, 0, '0', "C", false);
```

i want to display like this :
**Tanggal 10 Agust - 15 Agust 2017**

But its just display this :
**Tanggal -**

How to display variable in my header ?

Comment: `$this->Cell(20, 0.5, 'Tanggal "'.$tg1."'" '.$bln1.'" - "'.$tg2.'" "'.$bln2.'" "'.$thn, 0, '0', "C", false);` Use this

Comment: thanks for your help. but its not word

Comment: we don't know what's in your variables or what you're expecting it to display. Please clarify.

Comment: i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

i think i have a solution. but its not the best solution.
i cant echoing a variable in function, so im echoing contents of the variable.
like this :

```
$this->Cell(20, 0.5, 'Tanggal '.substr($_GET['tgl1'],8).'etc...', 0, '0', "C", false);
```

**Please comment if there is a better way**